# dict comprehension with nested loop based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a nested `dict` that I want to flatten. The `dict` is only one layer deep and the nested elements are either `dict` or `str`. So given the example data below:

```
data = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'sample': {
        'a': 213,
        'b': 634298,
        'c': 1},
    'doo': 'val',
    'spaz': {
        'x': 4,
        'y': 32,
        'z': 18}}
```

Desired output is a flattened `dict` as follows:

```
{'foo': 'bar', 
 'sample_a': 213, 
 'sample_b': 634298, 
 'sample_c': 1, 
 'doo': 'val',
 'spaz_x': 4, 
 'spaz_y': 32, 
 'spaz_z': 18}
```

The traditional way I'd do this is a loop such as this:

```
data_out = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        for ik, iv in v.items():
            data_out[f'{k}_{ik}'] = iv
    else:
        data_out[k] = v
```

Although I'm looking to see how I can do this cleanly with a comprehension. My attempt uses a conditional nested loop along with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

```
data_out = dict(chain.from_iterable(((f'{k}_{ik}', iv) for ik, iv in v.items()) if isinstance(v, dict) else ((k, v),) for k, v in data.items()))
```

Below is the same thing as above only broken down by line for readability:

```
data_out = dict(chain.from_iterable(
               ((f'{k}_{ik}', iv) for ik, iv in v.items()) 
                   if isinstance(v, dict)
                   else ((k, v),)
               for k, v in data.items()))
```

While this works I'm convinced this more than needed, I just cannot think of a better way preferably as a traditional `dict` comprehension and not using `dict` on a generator comprehension. Only way I can really shorten the code that I can think of is removing `.from_iterable` and just star unpacking the generator although I don't think this is more optimal for this approach.

Comment: You could probably just flatten the logic in your original snippet down to a dict comprehension with a ternary conditional in it but honestly that would be a PITA to debug when it goes wrong. you'd be better off leaving it as it is

Comment: Can you do a regular nested loop based on a condition like that? And wouldn't you need to repeat the condition check for the loop and for the output stage?

Comment: I'm sure its doable if really wanted to come up with a code golf answer but it would be ugly af and less performant

Answer (score 2):

You could invert the order of the loops in your dict comprehension and thus create the "flat" dictionary directly, without `chain.from_iterable`, but that does not really make it any clearer.

```
>>> {k: v for (k1, v1) in data.items()
...       for (k, v) in (((f'{k1}_{k2}', v2) for (k2, v2) in v1.items())
...                      if isinstance(v1, dict) else ((k1, v1),))}
...
{'doo': 'val',
 'foo': 'bar',
 'sample_a': 213,
 'sample_b': 634298,
 'sample_c': 1,
 'spaz_x': 4,
 'spaz_y': 32,
 'spaz_z': 18}
```

Another way might be to create two dicts and then `**`-combine them to the final dict:

```
>>> {**{   k1:        v1 for (k1, v1) in data.items() if isinstance(v1, str)},
...  **{f'{k1}_{k2}': v2 for (k1, v1) in data.items() if isinstance(v1, dict)
...                      for (k2, v2) in v1.items()}}
```

However, IMHO your "traditional" nested loop is much cleaner than either of those three versions. Alternatively, just use any of the other recursive "flatten dictionary with arbitrary depth" functions found here.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out a way I can do this using `getattr` as a shortcut to checking if its a `dict` or not. To me this is more efficient than other ways I’ve seen:

```
data_out = {'_'.join(filter((0).__ne__, [pk, sk])): v 
                     for pk, v in data.items() 
                     for sk, v in getattr(v, 'items', {0: v}.items)()}
```

**Legend:**

> `pk` - *parent_key*
>   `sk` - *suffix_key* or *sub_key*

And if you may have `0`'s in your keys I just used a *"trasher"* object:

```
fill = object(); nfill = fill.__ne__
data_out = {'_'.join(filter(nfill, [pk, sk])): v 
                      for pk, v in data.items() 
                      for sk, v in getattr(v, 'items', {fill:v}.items)()}
```